# docker compose on mac m1 error: Function not implemented

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, arm, apple-m1

i'm use new mac book with m1

if docker compose up, one of the containers throws an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented

at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()

at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()

at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)

at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()

at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()

 

at BackOffice.Host.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args)

qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped

Aborted
```

please tell me what could be the reason and how you can get rid of this error

Comment: Hi feel007.  Welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you post the docker-compose.yml file that you're using, along with any relevant Dockerfiles?  And are you invoking docker-compose from terminal?  And lastly, is there any additional error info above the unhandled exception?

Answer (score 1):

> It’s related to docker compose v2 beta which is experimental feature

[Here](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-up-returns-not-implemented-what-worng/111914/10?u=jagomez)